# jQuery add text to end of a URL

Tags: jquery, url, href

I have this code:

```
$('a.comment-reply-link').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace("dummy_comment", "author");
    this.href = this.href.replace("#comment-", "?replytocom=");
});
```

This is working but now i want on the end of the url #respond. So i made the code as:

```
$('a.comment-reply-link').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace("dummy_comment", "author");
    this.href = this.href.replace("#comment-", "?replytocom=");
    
    this.href + '#respond';
});
```

But this is not working? How can i make it work?

Comment: try with this.href += '#respond';

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

this.href + '#respond';

to this

this.href += '#respond';

Comment: Its now when you have clicked the link the page refresh the url change to: example.net/author/?replytocom=4212. But the reply links change then to example.net/author/?replytocom=4212?replytocom=4212 how can i avoid this?